# Как обновить систему андроид на Самсунг А8 + до 10-11-12 анроид версии самостоятельно без компьютера с телефона

Tags: android

Андроид 9 обновление до 12 версии андроид

Comment: Никак. Данный телефон прекратили поддерживать его производители, последняя официальная прошивка для него от 20 года, базируется на 9 версии андройда. Для неофициальной прошивки (которые есть на 11 андройде) нужен разблокированный загрузчик, и измененный рекавери, через который уже можно потом поставить нужную прошивку без компьютера, но чтоб все это сделать, нужен компьютер и спец. утилиты, а также знание, осознание того, что будут удалены все данные, осознание того, что телефон может лагать, и т.д. Об этом всем можете почитать на [4pda](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=890928).